# How can I group a set of table rows to overflow scroll (without using thead or tbody)?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a table with 100 rows.  My `thead` and `tbody` are already used.  But I need to allow another set of table rows scroll without making the rest of the page scroll.  How can I do this?

Here's a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/hMEuC/ and here's some markup:

```
<table>
    <thead><tr><th>header</th></tr></thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr><td>abc<td></tr>
        <tr><td>def<td></tr>
        <tr><td>ghi<td></tr>

        <!-- Can I make these rows overflow auto scroll? -->

        <tr><td>abc<td></tr>
        <tr><td>def<td></tr>
        <tr><td>ghi<td></tr>
        ...
        <tr><td>xyz<td></tr>

        <!-- end hopeful autoscroll box -->

    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is [perfectly legal](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/tabular-data.html#the-table-element) (See *content model*) to use multiple `tbody` elements within a `table`. If you have a set of table rows that you would like to target, wrap them in their own `tbody`, and target that.

You will have to set the display of the second `tbody` to something like `block` so that you can set the overflow of y-axis to auto. This will require re-working the nested `tr` and `td` elements as well.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sycAT/2/

Comment: @Ryan It blew my mind when I learned it too ;) Little things you pick up on when you sit down to read the specification. If you've not done so yet, I'd suggest spending a few hours in it over a week.

Comment: Can you scroll individual table bodies with respect to the table though? I suspect that's what's being asked.

Comment: Unfortunately it also screws with the widths of the `td`'s, so my `th`'s is now not matching my `td`'s.

Comment: @Ryan You'll have to fix the `display` of the `tbody`, `tr`, and `td` elements. See fiddle above.

Comment: Thanks Jonathan. This is interesting. Can I bend your ear for one more round? A more complex table misaligns everything.  Here's a fork of your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/YYAxk/  Notice how all of the second tbody compresses into the width of the first td of the wrapping table.  This was fine for 1 column, but can you help me out with more than one?

Comment: @Ryan I suspect the fields are not all fixed-width either, are they?

Comment: @JonathanSampson, I took a look at your (so far unpublished) fiddle update (http://jsfiddle.net/YYAxk/1/) and noticed that you had to get fixed-width columns in order to get this to work.  This matches my research as well.  But in case you don't come back or find a fluid-width option, I think others should see your progress.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: I'm awarding you the answer, but the problem of multiple columns without a fixed-width remains.  I think the multiple `tbody`'s deserves all the points by itself. ;)  Just tidying up in the meantime.

Comment: @Ryan Thank you. My answer does address the code you provided in the question ;) That being said, I still have a tab opened where I'm working through ideas for your extended issue. I'll update here if I come across a reliable solution. All of my searching has suggested that this is A) Impossible given how primitive tables are, and B) Most definitely will require JavaScript to even get close to a solution.

Comment: Yes, I'm looking toward a JS solution at this point as well.  Thanks for your attention and interest.